# 2nd Opinion on AC repair

Tags: repair, air-conditioning

I moved into a newly built house 4 years ago.

I had complained to the builder about the AC not being that cold - it's cool but not as cold as every other AC that I've had. It cools of the house but takes a while.

A few days later, guy calls and says he checked my AC and it's find and that I can't expect to get cold air. I had said it takes forever to cool the house and he says it's a energy-efficient model that I need to keep on all the time.

So now a few years later, I call for a checkup/cleaning. The guy (not the same AFAIK) says it's not that cold and the freon is low. He said he would check it out and spent about 5 minutes by the AC and came back and said my coil is leaking. Got a call the next day that parts were covered but it $2500 for labor and freon.

This sounds a little fishy to me. If there's a leak, wouldn't ALL the freon leak out and I wouldn't have any freon left to cool the house? It sounds to me like the freon has always been low and the leak is an excuse as to why it's not their fault but I couldn't just paranoid.

Comment: The forced air AC unit is working the most efficiently when leaving it on at a constant temperature.  I usually call HVAC service in alternate years, maintenance is cheap compared to one shoot repair. $2500 is way too expensive (maybe the COVID effect), you shall check at least another two estimates.

Comment: When AC is first stated , it requires many hours to dehumidify the air .  The cooling capacity is used condensing water more than cooling air. That is why running AC a couple days , then opening windows for a few days of nice weather is very expensive.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - I hadn't thought of that but it's pretty dry here - 11% outdoor and 29% inside.

Comment: It should cool  quickly with that low humidity.

Comment: two things seem true to me: 1. the new guy might be right about a leak, they can behave non-linearly as weather and conditions change. 2. $2500 is pretty steep for a recharge with no coil repair.

Comment: Even if your system was r21  that is two much to pay, I could install a 10 ton system and provide the refrigerant for less it really sounds like a scam, what refrigerant? R134a, 404, 410?  8-12 lbs if something is wrong what is it? A pump down is it needed? it’s working so there is some refrigerant left. The rip-off masters started charging 100/lb since the r21 actually got expensive and started doing it with refrigerant that I can purchase 30 lbs for under 200$ so they are charging way more plus truck time that’s way out of line. For an operational system.

Comment: @EdBeal - it's actually a 4 year-old Goodman that uses 410a. The $2500 is for the labor of replacing the coil and the 410. I assume it's the outside coil - I asked about the labor and was told it was a two-man job to replace. My main concern is that the AC wasn't completely filled when new and they are just assuming its a leak.

Answer (score 2):

I can purchase a new 25 lb cylinder of R410A online 160$

Brand new 5 ton outside unit 1700.00  includes shipping.

how many ton is the system? Goodman is a low cost system but if properly installed it should last 10+ years,

If there is a leak it was small the system is still cooling right.

you wanted a second opinion if the unit is smaller the cost is less. The outside unit includes the compressor, controls, coil, fan etc.

A coil would be much less expensive.

I smell a scam just saying.